# Python find duplicate adjacent sequences in list

Tags: python, list, cycle

I have a list of positive integer numbers (indices) and want to find cycles (here: ***duplicate adjacent sequences of list elements***) as part of an iterative algorithm. The number of iterations is less than 10^6. In every iteration, one number is appended to the list (initially the list is empty) and the list should be checked for cycles. The list size should typically be less than 10^6, usually in the range 0 - 10^5, and the integers will likely be smaller than 10^6.

Examples for lists with cycles (here, more generally, the lists may extend beyond cycles and may contain multiple, even nested, cycles):

- [0,5,6,1,3,5,6,1,3,8,7,0] --> [5,6,1,3]
- [0,2,4,3,3,3,0,1,6,7] --> [3],[3]
- [2,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,4,5] --> [1],[3],[1],[3],[1,1,3,3]
- [7,6,2,3,2,1,7,1,9,1,7,1,9,0,4] --> [1,7,1,9]

Examples for lists with no cycles:

- [0,5,6,3,5,6,1,3,8,7,0]
- [0,2,4,0,1,6,7]
- [2,1,3,4,5]
- [7,6,2,3,2,1,7,1,9,1,7,1,0,4]

**What is the fastest (and optionally most elegant/pythonic) way to****

- **find if there are cycles, return True or False**, and
- optionally: return all cycles, with or without any kind of cycle ordering (e.g. by index of first cycle element in list, then by cycle length)?

Comment: So you have a loop of 10^6 iterations and each iteration you either add or don't add a number to a list, and after you add a number, you want to check the list for cycles?

Comment: It is a very broad question. Please try researching the problem and existing solutions. Then come here for a more specific problem (if you encounter any) with an example of the code you've tried.

Comment: The number of iterations is not fixed, but in each iteration a number is added to the list. If there is a cycle, then the algorithm should do something different to not run into a loop. The algorithm will stop when some criterion is fulfilled (convergence, max. number of iterations, etc.).

Comment: I think there's a way to do this using suffix trees or something similar.

Comment: Are you able to assume a limit on the length of a cycle?

Comment: @fishstix44: No, I cannot assume a limit on the cycle length, apart from that the cycles cannot be larger than half the total list size in each iteration.

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. It could be worded better, but it is a specific question about an algorithm for online detection of subsequence repetitions.

Comment: mylist=[0,5,6,1,3,5,6,1,3,8,7,0] s="" s=s.join([str(x) for x in mylist]) string_length=len(s) sequence_length=len(mylist)/2 print(sequence_length) dups=[] for i in range(2,int(sequence_length)-1):    old_offset=0    segments=string_length/i    print("Segments ",segments)    for k in range(0,string_length-1):  old_offset=k        myDct={}  for j in range(1,int(segments)+1):  offset=k+j*I if offset<=string_length:  key=s[old_offset:offset]  if key in myDct.keys():  myDct[key]+=1 print(key,old_offset,offset,myDct[key])  dups.append(key)  else: myDct[key]=1   old_offset=offset print(dups)

Comment: You then take the dup list and split it into single elements then apply set producing the unique values

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can give.

```py
from math import floor
sample = samples[0]
def find_max_seq(sample):
    max_possible_size_ans = floor(len(sample)/2)
    possible_size_ans = list(range(1,max_possible_size_ans+1))
    max_idx = len(sample)-1
    outs = []
    for size in possible_size_ans:
        last_idx= 0
        start_idx = 0
        while last_idx < max_idx :
            first_pair = sample[start_idx:start_idx+size]
            second_start = start_idx+size
            second_pair = sample[second_start:second_start+size]
            if first_pair == second_pair:
                outs.append(first_pair)
            start_idx +=1
            last_idx = second_start+size
            
    return outs
```